# seq2seq embedding size is too large for distributed training

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trained `sequence to sequence with attention` model with tensorflow. I have 3 servers and each server has 32 cpu and 8 Titan X gpu.

When I trained this model with single server and single gpu, it utilized gpu 50~60% continuously. step-time also reasonable(0.2~0.3 sec).

However, when I trained same model with cluster(1 parameter server, 2 workers with async), they can't utilize gpu and step-time increased (3 sec, which is 10 times slower than single version.)

I found that the size of parameters is 220MB and network usage is 2Gbits/sec for parameter server. I think there is the way to reduce parameter update frequency, but I can't find.

Is there way to solve this problem?

- reduce parameter update frequency.
- reduce embedding parameters with no information loss.
- other solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach may be to use an input projection layer and lower your embedding size by a factor of 8x. In this way, the majority of the parameters in your model will be reduced and hopefully improve transfer speeds.

I don't know what your task is but its also helpful to share embeddings -- as in the encoder and decoder share the same embedding which reduce parameters by another factor of 2x.